# how to get the stack region allocated to the current process in Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, stack

In case of Windows OS, Thread Information Block(TIB) contains information regarding the currently executing thread, including addresses of bottom and top of stack. However in Linux, how to get the similar information? Does Thread Specific Data(TSD) help?

Comment: Your title says "current process".  If you mean "current thread", then you should retitle.

Comment: To be simplified, currently I only consider current process.

Comment: The current process includes all the threads of the current process...  So you mean simplify by assuming a single-threaded process?

Comment: Yes. I want to check whether the value in esp register is out of the stack, like pointing to heap or data section.

Comment: That never happens in compiler-generated code, unless a `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` function (e.g. one using variable-length arrays) corrupted a saved a saved `rbp` value.  Then when *its* caller's epilogue runs, `rsp` will contain garbage for one instruction before `ret` causes a segfault by loading a bogus return address.  In hand-written asm, it's possible to stash `esp` somewhere (e.g. in an MMX register) and use it as an 8th general-purpose register in a loop that doesn't need the stack and can't be interrupted by a signal handler.  But then there's no guarantee it's a pointer at all.

Answer (score 1):

A program can find the bounds of the memory-mapped region dedicated to the stack by reading the file named `/proc/self/maps`. Use the man page for `proc` to see how best to read the `maps` file. Amongst other things, it gives the start address, end address, permissions and size for each memory region.

You can search for a region containing an address that you know is on the stack. One region will be labelled `[stack]`, but I think that only represents the main thread.

Comment: The current thread knows it's own stack pointer, so it can just check what mapping contains its own stack pointer.  Without using any asm, probably the easiest way to get a stack address is to take the address of a dummy local variable.  But yeah, looking in `/proc/self/maps` is what I was thinking, too.

Comment: Actually, for multithreaded processes, the stack mappings are tagged like `[stack:2681]`.  So a thread can just look for its own PID's stack in `/proc/self/maps` instead of doing a range check.

Comment: I am instrumenting a program for which I want to check the stack region. It had better be implemented in the form of assembly. I know that by reading /proc/pid/stat I can get startstack address and by reading /proc/pid/status I can get the size of stack segment. Alternatively, I can also get the maximum size of the process stack by calling getrlimit(). Despite all this, I still do not know how to write in assembly? @Peter Cordes

Comment: @Matthewxie: You can write a function to open/read/parse `/proc/self/maps` or whatever, and use a compiler to make asm out of that.  That will make too much code to duplicate all over the place, but you can call it from all over the place.  Or cache that info, since adding a lot of system calls while instrumenting is not at all ideal.  The info *might* already be cached in the thread-local data, but I've never done anything with thread-local data except for being aware that x86-64 uses a segment register override to access it.

Comment: Also note that there's a `sigaltstack(2)` system call, which sets up an alt stack for signal handlers.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I am working with Linux 32bit. So the TLS method may not work. The approach that disassembling a function opening/reading/parse /proc/self/maps indeed incurs considerable performance penalty. What about modifying the kernel to write addresses of bottom and top of stack allocated to the process to a specific location such as 0x0100_0000. In such a way I can just use a single instruction like mov eax, [0x01000000] to retrieve the range of stack. Will this idea feasible?

Comment: @PeterCordes What I need is the lowest and highest addresses of the stack allocated to the process by the kernel rather than the current dynamic stack region.

Comment: @Matthewxie Perhaps write some C code that runs shortly after your program starts up, which will obtain the bounds of the stack (start/stop) from `/proc` using the methods discussed here. The bounds are then stored within two global variables. Then your assembly code only needs to compare `$esp` to those global variables. This is a bit like the solution you mentioned with `mov $eax,0x1000000`, but you don't have to hard-code the address, you can use a symbol for that. If you're new to assembly, write the code in C first and then use `gcc -S` to turn it into assembly.

Comment: @JackWhitham: yup, that's what I meant by caching it somewhere.  You could cache it within the TLS area, so something like `mov eax, [gs:0x40]` (aka `mov %gs:0x40, %eax`) would work.  (I checked disassembly output of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` because I always forget whether FS or GS is used for TLS.  It's `gs`.  Or `cmp [gs:0x40], esp / jb error / cmp [gs:0x44], esp / ja error` to compare the low and high bounds.  This lets you avoid instructions to save/restore any register when instrumenting, but means you can't use `(esp-min) < (max-min)` unsigned compare trick to use one fewer branch